# Hermitian Matrix and its Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

Suppose B is an N x N Hermitian matrix with $\lambda _i$ eigenvalues. if  $w_k$ are any orthonormal real-valued vectors. I need to prove that
\begin{equation}
\sum _{k=1}^N\left(w_k^TBw_k\right)\:=\:\sum _{k=1}^N\left(\lambda _k\right)
\end{equation}
Here's what I know so far

Since $B$ is Hermitian, then $B = Q\Lambda Q^H$ Where $Q$ is the eigenvector matrix of $B$ and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $B$

now $B$ can be represented as $B = \sum _{j=1}^N\left(\lambda _jq_jq^H_j\right)$

If we substitute that in the original question, we get
\begin{equation}
\sum _{k=1}^N\left(w_i^T\sum _{j=1}^N\left(\lambda _jq_jq_j^H\right)w_i\right)\
\end{equation}

But am confused on what to do from here. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative argument to the one presented in the other answer: we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum _{k=1}^N\left(w_k^TBw_k\right) &= 
\sum _{k=1}^N\left(\sum _{j=1}^Nw_k^H\left(\lambda _jq_jq_j^H\right)w_k\right)
\\ & = 
\sum_{j=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^N  \lambda_j \,(w_k^Hq_j)( w_k q_j^H)
\\ & = 
\sum_{j=1}^N \lambda_j \left(\sum_{k=1}^N (w_k^Hq_j)( w_k q_j^H)\right)
\\ & = 
\sum_{j=1}^N \lambda_j \left(\sum_{k=1}^N |w_k^Hq_j|^2\right)
= \sum_{j=1}^N \lambda_j \cdot 1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

In terms of matrices, the sum is just $\operatorname{tr}(W^TBW)$. Since $W$ is orthogonal, $W^TBW$ is similar to $B$. Therefore $\operatorname{tr}(W^TBW)$ is equal to $\operatorname{tr}(B)$, which in turn is equal to the sum of all eigenvalues of $B$.

Comment: thank you so much for your input. But don't I need to put B in terms of its eigenvalues and eigenvectors since W is just any arbitrary orthonormal vector?

Comment: @Raykh You don't need eigendecomposition of $B$. The key is that $W^TW=I$. Therefore $W^T=W^{-1}$.